Highlight certain points in Plotly through dropbown bar
I am trying to make an interactive PCA plot  with Plotly. I am having some troubles in highlighting a certain marker that a user wants to see in the plot.
Instead of highlighting a marker there is a square around it.
My attempt at the code:
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=30, centers=3, n_features=2,
                  random_state=0)
ff = PCA(n_components=  2)
clusters = pd.DataFrame(data = ff.fit_transform(X), columns = ['PC1', 'PC2'])
clusters['target'] = y
id = [0, 4, 7]
updatemenus = [dict(buttons=list(dict(label = idd ,method = 'relayout', args = ['shapes', [dict(markers = dict(color = 'Red', size = 120), type = "markers", xref = 'x', yref = 'y', x0 = clusters.loc[idd, 'PC1'], y0=clusters.loc[idd, 'PC2'])]]) for idd in id))]
fig = px.scatter(clusters, x = 'PC1', y = 'PC2', color = 'target', hover_data = ['target'])
fig.update_layout(updatemenus = updatemenus)
fig.show()


What am I doing wrong :)

Using shapes
The shape type should be one of 'circle' | 'rect' | 'path' | 'line', I guess you might want to use 'circle'instead of 'markers'.
fig = px.scatter(clusters, x='PC1', y='PC2', color='target', hover_data=['target'])

size = 1/100 # ~1% of the x|y range
rx = (clusters['PC1'].max() - clusters['PC1'].min()) * size
ry = (clusters['PC2'].max() - clusters['PC2'].min()) * size

updatemenus = [dict(
    buttons=[dict(
        label='None',
        method='relayout',
        args=['shapes', []]
    )] + [dict(
        label=idd,
        method='relayout',
        args=[{
            'xaxis.autorange': True,
            'yaxis.autorange': True,
            'shapes': [{
                'type': 'circle',
                'layer': 'below',
                'xref': 'x',
                'yref': 'y',
                'x0': clusters.loc[idd, 'PC1'] - rx,
                'y0': clusters.loc[idd, 'PC2'] - ry,
                'x1': clusters.loc[idd, 'PC1'] + rx,
                'y1': clusters.loc[idd, 'PC2'] + ry,
                'opacity': 0.3,
                'fillcolor': 'red',
                'line': {
                    'color': 'red'
                }
            }]
        }]
    ) for idd in id]
)]

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()



Using a scatter trace
You could also use a scatter trace dedicated to highlighting instead of using shapes, eg.
fig = px.scatter(clusters, x='PC1', y='PC2', color='target', hover_data=['target'])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name='highlight',
    mode='markers',
    showlegend=False,
    hoverinfo='skip',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        color='red'
    )
))

updatemenus = [dict(
    buttons=[dict(
        label='None',
        method='relayout',
        args=[{
            'x': [clusters['PC1']],
            'y': [clusters['PC2']]
        }]
    )] + [dict(
        label=idd,
        method='restyle',
        args=[{
            'x': [clusters['PC1'], [clusters.loc[idd, 'PC1']]],
            'y': [clusters['PC2'], [clusters.loc[idd, 'PC2']]]
        }]
    ) for idd in id]
)]

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()



No, may my question wasnt clear. I dont want to draw circle around it. I want to paint it red and enlarge it. that it stands out

Ok, in this case instead of using shapes you could use another trace with either no marker or one highlighted marker, see revised answer.
